# How to perform an offline upgrade on Ubuntu to the next LTS version?

Tags: upgrade, offline

The issue that we have multiple devices running on Ubuntu 16. The task is to perform an upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 and later to 20.04 It's not possible for the devices to perform normal upgrade through connecting to ubuntu servers for security reasons. So instead if we can somehow have the files needed in the upgrade put on a separate storage, and then perform the upgrade.

Comment: Will a fresh install work for you? It works offline.

Comment: The devices are remote, so is it feasible to perform a fresh installation. Also, the fresh installation will clear the data on the devices, No?

Comment: Fresh install will only clear the root partition. Other partitions would not be affected. I don't know if you can perform a fresh installation on a remote device. You may be able to boot from network, but that may be complicated. *Let's wait for someone else with more experience to comment or answer*.

Comment: Yes, the devices we are performing the upgrade on, are not partitioned. So all the data are on the same partition. So fresh installation is not feasible in this case. Thank you for your responses anyway.

Comment: Ubuntu 16 implies you're using Ubuntu Core 16 (or other *snap* only *year* release) which do **not** upgrade to the *deb* based 18.04 (*year.month* format) as they are different products.  Ubuntu has used the *year* format for *snap* only products since 2016; which are different (longer support lives; when you upgrade no apps are upgraded as *snaps* are the same for all releases so no need etc).  Please clarify

Comment: I am running an LTS version, and I want to upgrade for the next one. Please don't misinterpret the question. The idea is not with the versions, but by how to perform the offline upgrade.

Comment: Maybe http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/apt-mirror.1.html apt-mirror can help.